# On Developing Mobile app using ionic and web api 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

web api is hosted on secure server and i am accessing it through a path locally it is working fine. but after hosting an api
I am Getting this error while running an application

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxxx.xxxxapp.net/xxx_API/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error give you an info about what to do. You are doing request with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). It says that your request does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` request header specified. So you should provide it. More about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: i think you have to specify it in request

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in your `ionic.project` file

`"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://xxxxx.xxxxapp.net/xxx_API/token"
    }
  ]
}`

and change the `proxuUrl` with your api path